# Не получается получить код при авторизации сайте через requests

Tags: python, парсер, requests

В общем, проблема такая, мне необходимо авторизоваться на сайте. Все перерыл, нигде не нашел решения. Но на сайте можно войти только через номер телефона, собственно в параметрах запроса только он и нужен. Процедура такая, ты вводишь номер телефона, тебе приходит уведомление в приложении, ты должен его подтвердить и тогда на сайте ты перенаправишься в личный кабинет. Вот код того, что писал через requests, там проблема была в том, что сообщение просто не приходило.

```
session = requests.Session()
url_zap='https://translations.telegram.org/auth'
url_zap1='https://translations.telegram.org'
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

header = {
    'user-agent':user
    }
data = {
    'phone': str(number1)
    }
r=session.post(url_zap, data=data, headers=header)
response = session.get(url_zap1, headers=header)
print(response.text)
```

Потом несколько решил проблему, сделав через selenium, с подтверждением в приложении проблем нет вот код

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://translations.telegram.org")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("phone-number")
element.send_keys(str(number1))
button_element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button")
button_element.click()
```

Можно ли то, что написано через selenium перенести в запросы через requests, т.к. я это подключаю к боту, и через браузер выполнять такое количество запросов нет возможности

Comment: data = {'phone': str(number1)} Почему вы решили что так и должно быть? У меня нет возможности проверить или подвертить вашу теорию описаную в коде

Comment: data = {'phone': str(number1) Это словарь  с датой, который передается сайту, тот же самый код прекрасно работал на githab только в дата надо было передать параметры login и password data = {'login': 'Никнейм', 'password':'Пароль от аккаунта'}, на этом сайте требуется только номер телефона, т.к. в коде страницы я других параметров не нашел

Comment: Я в курсе что такое словарь в Питоне. 'код прекрасно работал на githab" если это работает на одном ресурсе, это не значит что будет работать на другом. "в коде страницы я других параметров не нашел" ну это не говорит, что их не существует

Comment: Прошу прощения за мою неграмотность, исправил вопрос и вставил ссылки на сам сайт в коде

Comment: Вроде все верно. Я проверял на прямую, без сессий с кукисами и хендлером взятые из браузера. На запрос data = {'phone': '+7мойномер')}  на 'https://translations.telegram.org/auth' пришел ответ в виде {"temp_session":"TygALXcQQRPiRs5ezu6rECl4"} плюс телеграмм прислал собщение. Почему у вас не работае? Мои предположения может быть не хватает каких то параметров в хендлерах или кукисах

Comment: Извините, не могли бы вы написать, как вы создали такой запрос, что у вас получилось? У меня напрямую так же не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'stel_ssid': 'adf692e8ed7762f7e7_22945729152833885675',
    'stel_lang': 'auth',
    'stel_dt': '-360',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Origin': 'https://translations.telegram.org',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://translations.telegram.org/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
}

data = {
    'phone': '+77051234567',
}

response = requests.post('https://translations.telegram.org/auth/request',
                         cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)
```